# How to fill up the value in the regrouped rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need your help to show me direction how to do my task.
I have to find the main reference by the value 'Pere'. After I have to group by 'Unit' and apply the value of the main reference 'Ref' to each 'Unit' group except the first.  After all I should to create the new dataframe with changed elements. My initail table is like this:

```
db_test = pd.DataFrame({'Ref': ['ref1','ref2','ref3','ref4','ref5','ref6', 'ref7'], 
                    'Unit': ['LT123','LT123', 'LT123', 'LT1234', 'LT1234', 'LT12345', 'LT12345'],
                    'Pere':[None, 1,None,None,1, None, None],
                    'Ref_pere': [None,None,None,None,None, None,None]})
```

Initial:

```
Ref Unit    Pere    Ref_pere
ref1    LT123   NaN None
ref2    LT123   1.0 None
ref3    LT123   NaN None
ref4    LT1234  NaN None
ref5    LT1234  1.0 None
ref6    LT12345 NaN None
ref7    LT12345 NaN None
```

The expected new Dataframe:

```
    Ref Unit    Pere    Ref_pere
ref2    LT123   1.0 None
ref1    LT123   NaN ref2
ref3    LT123   NaN ref2
ref5    LT1234  1.0 None
ref4    LT1234  NaN ref5
ref6    LT12345 NaN None
ref7    LT12345 NaN None
```

I group and I sort, now how to fill up the 'Ref_pere' by the 'Ref' value except the first:

```
for inunit, inrow in db_test.groupby('Unit'):
    b = inrow.sort_values(by=['Pere'], ascending=True)
    print(b)

   Ref   Unit  Pere Ref_pere
1  ref2  LT123   1.0     None
0  ref1  LT123   NaN     None
2  ref3  LT123   NaN     None
   Ref    Unit  Pere Ref_pere
4  ref5  LT1234   1.0     None
3  ref4  LT1234   NaN     None
   Ref     Unit  Pere Ref_pere
5  ref6  LT12345   NaN     None
6  ref7  LT12345   NaN     None
```

I found the answer by myself. The construction of the loop is quite heavy. Maybe there is another way to get it:

```
test = []
test1 = []
test2 = []
for inunit, inrow in db_test.groupby('Unit'):
    b = inrow.sort_values(by=['Pere'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    for ind, row in b.iterrows():
        if ind == 0 and row['Pere'] == 1:
            code = row['Ref']
            b.loc[1:, 'Ref_pere'] = code
            test1 = [i for i in b.values.tolist()]
            test = test + test1       
        elif ind == 0 and row['Pere'] !=1:
            test2 = [i for i in b.values.tolist()]
            test = test + test2
        else:
            pass

d = pd.DataFrame(test, columns=['Ref', 'Unit', 'Pere', 'Ref_pere'])
print(d)

Ref     Unit  Pere Ref_pere
0  ref2    LT123   1.0     None
1  ref1    LT123   NaN     ref2
2  ref3    LT123   NaN     ref2
3  ref5   LT1234   1.0     None
4  ref4   LT1234   NaN     ref5
5  ref6  LT12345   NaN     None
6  ref7  LT12345   NaN     None
```